# Why security tools related questions are closed one after one?

Tags: discussion

On [What topics can I ask about here?](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I read that asking about *security tools* (not to be confused with software recommendations) is on-topic. However, I see these type of questions are closed one after one in the name of: *Ask the producer support.*

I see this as a contradiction: either we remove the security tools section from on-topic questions either we leave open related questions.

Personally, I want to leave open all  questions asking clarifications/information about security tools.

What is the right thing to do?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your other question: http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/1955/6253 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we're often too quick to close questions that ask about how to use security tools.   This really is, or should be, the right audience for at least many of those questions.

I think there may be some confusion about what qualifies as a security tool used for information security purposes vs. more general use tools that may be used for security purposes, and in that second case, there may in fact be a more appropriate site more familiar with their use.  That's ok, but it seems to have spiraled into a "close any question where an OP asks how to use a tool" which is not in the spirit of the site charter.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the closed questions about security tools (at least the ones I close) are not that they are about security tools, but that they are questions that:

1. can only be answered by the developer (requires knowledge of the code)
2. the tool has their own support page or online support

There are tons of tools questions that are allowed. I also reference my decision matrix outlined in this Answer to your similar question:

[Contradiction towards the policy regarding on-topic subjects?](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1955/contradiction-towards-the-policy-regarding-on-topic-subjects)

Comment: Thank you. In fact, it is because I received a flag regarding [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103509/what-is-the-difference-between-ftp-brute-force-with-hydra-and-metasploit) a moment ago. I admit you covered what I wanted to ask precisely on here through the link you provided.